# Writing Dockerfile file for installation of opencv

Tags: c, docker, opencv, dockerfile

I'm writing a Dockerfile to install the C version of OpenCV.

I have found a working solution for the Python version, which looks like this.

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 

# Various Python and C/build deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    wget \
    build-essential \ 
    cmake \ 
    git \
    unzip \ 
    pkg-config \
    python-dev \ 
    python-opencv \ 
    libopencv-dev \ 
    libav-tools  \ 
    libjpeg-dev \ 
    libpng-dev \ 
    libtiff-dev \ 
    libjasper-dev \ 
    libgtk2.0-dev \ 
    python-numpy \ 
    python-pycurl \ 
    libatlas-base-dev \
    gfortran \
    webp \ 
    python-opencv \ 
    qt5-default \
    libvtk6-dev \ 
    zlib1g-dev 

# Install Open CV - Warning, this takes absolutely forever
RUN mkdir -p ~/opencv cd ~/opencv && \
    wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.0.0.zip && \
    unzip 3.0.0.zip && \
    rm 3.0.0.zip && \
    mv opencv-3.0.0 OpenCV && \
    cd OpenCV && \
    mkdir build && \ 
    cd build && \
    cmake \
    -DWITH_QT=ON \ 
    -DWITH_OPENGL=ON \ 
    -DFORCE_VTK=ON \
    -DWITH_TBB=ON \
    -DWITH_GDAL=ON \
    -DWITH_XINE=ON \
    -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. && \
    make -j4 && \
    make install && \ 
    ldconfig

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

My problem is that I don't know to change it to install the C version. Do I really need to put the whole installation procedure as written [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/)? I don't need the newest version. 3.x would be awesome.

Comment: C version is not supported anymore (I think after 3.4 and onwards?), so your link will not help you. You need to find an older version

Comment: @unlut As written in the description, I look out only for the older version 3.x

Comment: Do you have a c++ compiler, or you need a pure C solution? If you have, you can compile/install with c++ compiler and use C bindings. I don't know a pure C solution.

Comment: I have a c++ compiler. Could you change up the RUN statement as an answer?

Comment: I tried to run C examples at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/c with a opencv version 3 (similar to yours), they were working with C API but I had to compile programs with g++ because some opencv headers had c++ dependencies.